# constrain within a triangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg, raphael

I am looking for a generic piece of code (javascript) that would work with jquery UI to constrain movement(drag) of a div within an triangle.

similar to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515900/how-to-constrain-movement-within-the-area-of-a-circle) but a triangle, and not a circle.

I would prefer the triangle to be defined as a rapheal svg like this...

```
(function() {
  Raphael.fn.triangle = function (cx, cy, r) {
  r *= 1.75;
  return this.path("M".concat(cx, ",", cy, "m0-", r * .58, "l", r * .5, ",", r * .87, "-", r, ",0z"));
};

var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("triangle"), "100%", "100%");
        var triangle = paper.triangle(100,100,90);
        triangle.attr("fill", "#444444");
        triangle.attr("stroke", "#444444");



$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#triangle svgnode", scroll: false });
```

looking forward to solutions.

I would like to note that the draggable element could also be a svg node if that is easier.

Comment: I don't think jQuery UI's containment allows for anything except squares.

Comment: @Duopixel actually this is possible by using the 'drag' event.  I'll put an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16131457/289203) which shows how to constrain a jquery draggable to an arbitrary path.

The trick is to alter the `ui.position` variables within the `drag` event, to constrain the movement.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the given answers actually show how to constrain a draggable to a triangular area, I thought I'd share this jsfiddle which demonstrates an actual working example.

I think the key here is not to focus so much on the "triangle" aspect but more importantly to realize a triangle is a polygon.  This allows us to address the issue head-on using many existing algorithms that relate to a point and a polygon.

This 2D Graph library [JavaScript 2D Graph Library](https://github.com/borgboyone/Graph) provides all the tools we need to solve this problem.  Mainly, each **Shape** has an associated function *constrain* which will constrain a **Point** to the inner area of a the **Shape** (the edge included) via a **LineSegment** that connects to the centroid of the **Shape**.  (It also looks like you can set the center point for the **Shape** as a second argument which would prove handy for concave **Polygon**'s.)

This jsFiddle [Triangle Constraint via jQuery UI Draggable](https://jsfiddle.net/borgboyone/y1o6gjaq/) uses the jQuery UI Draggable *drag* callback in conjunction with the Graph library to do the constraint.  It actually uses the coordinates of the SVG Polygon to construct the Graph Polygon only inverting the y-axis to switch between screen and Cartesian coordinates.

The set-up that takes place in document ready is fairly simple:

```
var points = $('polygon').attr('points').trim().split(' ').map(function(vertex) { var coordinates = vertex.split(','); return new aw.Graph.Point(Number(coordinates[0]), Number(-coordinates[1])); }),
    triangle = new aw.Graph.Polygon(points);
$('.map-selector').draggable({
    containment: '.map',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var left = ui.position.left, top = -ui.position.top;
        var constrained = triangle.constrain(new aw.Graph.Point(left, top));
        ui.position.left = constrained.x; ui.position.top = -constrained.y;
    }
});
```

Cheers!