# JQuery UI draggable within a triangle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div (it's a rectangle of course) with an image of a triangle as background. I want to move an image of a circle inside the triangle.

I chose JQuery UI's draggable to use but i couldn't manage to constrain the draggable image within the triangle.

I thought i should use the *containment* option with an array but i can't define a triangle with two coordinates.

Then i found this topic: [constrain within a triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583832/constrain-within-a-triangle)

There the answer is pretty good but it uses a sinus curve and  i've got no idea how to define a triangle as the path to use.

Anyone can help how i should constrain the circle's movement to the triangle?

Comment: You forgot to link the topic you mentioned

Comment: Also, what are your browser support requirements?

Comment: Oh, here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583832/constrain-within-a-triangle

I want to embed it into an iBook project as a html widget so basically i think any webkit browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friends came up with a really simple and nice solution: [see it](http://jsfiddle.net/EhAB6/)

```
$( "#circle" ).draggable({
drag: function(e, ui) {

    var width = $('#triangle').width();
    var height = $('#triangle').height();

    var x = ui.position.left + $(this).width() / 2;
    var y = ui.position.top + $(this).height() / 2;

    var difference = Math.abs( x - width / 2 );
    var min_y = height * ( difference / (width / 2) );
    if ( y < min_y ) y = min_y;

    if ( x < 0 ) x = 0;
    if ( y < 0 ) y = 0;
    if ( x > width ) x = width;
    if ( y > height ) y = height;

    ui.position.top = y - $(this).height() / 2;
    ui.position.left = x - $(this).width() / 2;

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post this solution given its elegance and simplicity.

I think the key here is not to focus so much on the "triangle" aspect but more importantly to realize a triangle is a polygon.  This allows us to address the issue head-on using many existing algorithms that relate to a point and a polygon.

This 2D Graph library [JavaScript 2D Graph Library](https://github.com/borgboyone/Graph) provides all the tools needed to solve this problem.  Mainly, each **Shape** has an associated function *constrain* which will constrain a **Point** to the inner area of a the **Shape** (the edge included) via a **LineSegment** that connects to the centroid of the **Shape**.  (It also looks like you can set the center point for the **Shape** as a second argument which would prove handy for concave **Polygon**'s.)

This jsFiddle [Triangle Constraint via jQuery UI Draggable](https://jsfiddle.net/borgboyone/y1o6gjaq/) uses the jQuery UI Draggable *drag* callback in conjunction with the Graph library to do the constraint.  It actually uses the coordinates of the SVG Polygon to construct the Graph Polygon only inverting the y-axis to switch between screen and Cartesian coordinates.

The set-up that takes place in document ready is fairly simple:

```
var points = $('polygon').attr('points').trim().split(' ').map(function(vertex) { var coordinates = vertex.split(','); return new aw.Graph.Point(Number(coordinates[0]), Number(-coordinates[1])); }),
    triangle = new aw.Graph.Polygon(points);
$('.map-selector').draggable({
    containment: '.map',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var left = ui.position.left, top = -ui.position.top;
        var constrained = triangle.constrain(new aw.Graph.Point(left, top));
        ui.position.left = constrained.x; ui.position.top = -constrained.y;
    }
});
```

Cheers!