# How to constrain jQuery draggable to both x and y axes

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

It's pretty easy to constrain a jQuery draggable to an axis like this:

```
$("#object").draggable({ axis: "x" });
```

But how can I constrain it to both x and y?  IOW, I want to allow both vertical and horizontal movement but nothing else (imagine rooks on a chess board).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make jQuery draggable with fixed X and Y axis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572950/how-to-make-jquery-draggable-with-fixed-x-and-y-axis)

Comment: Possible dup of that post, but it's from 2009.  Has there really been no native (non-plugin) way of constraining drag movement to both axes instead of just one?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: @fudgey - Perhaps I missed it, I didn't see where in the docs it mentions how to constrain an object to two dimensions at the same time.  Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: hiya, +1 for the question have you tried this [code]   $( "#objectbar" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });
    $( "#objectfoo" ).draggable({ axis: "x" }); ? keen to help you out if you need help.

Comment: hiya again, try this man - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398854/jquery-draggable-with-ease   ; there is a sectio update:constraint axis draggable: [code] - $.fn.draggableXYE hope it helps!

Comment: @tats_innit - From your fist comment, the issue is I want #objectfoo to be constrained on both x and y.  Your example shows two different objects with the different constraints on each.  Think of a rook on a chess board.  It is a single object that can only move vertically or horizontally for any one move.  About your 2nd comment, I was hoping to avoid 3rd party plugins if possible.  Thanks for the comments though!

Comment: @Robot: If you look at the demo code, you can see that there is a [`containment` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment), just add a selector to contain the object within that element: `$("#draggable").draggable({ containment: selector });

Answer (score 1):

Just add this it works

```
$("#object").draggable({ axis: "x,y" });
```