# How to make an element draggable via jquery not ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I want to use draggable feature of jQuery UI without actually using UI.

jQuery UI size on minified customization: **25.8 Kb**

It doesn't make sense - using jQuery UI just to drag an element

Is there a small plugin/script available?

EXTRA DETAILS *[The answer must fulfill this] : I want to drag an element vertically*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572950/how-to-make-jquery-draggable-with-fixed-x-and-y-axis

Comment: **25.8 Kb** is nothing.

Comment: @safarov Not if you already have a heavy site OR you want the site to be accessible to the people in Antarctica with slow internet connection

Comment: @gpasci That does apply to this question. I don't want to use jQuery UI

Comment: I was able to get it down to 8KB by selecting only the Core, Mouse, Position and Draggables to be compiled before download.

Comment: Read through gpasci's link... The answer includes code for a standalone plugin which answers your question

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry, you might be mistaken. That's the size inside a zip file, after extraction its **28.5 Kb**

Comment: @Ohgodwhy. **8k instead of 25.8k** a tremendous change.

Comment: @tunetosuraj But you should zip it anyway, so it will be 8Kb

Comment: @JuanMendes It appears that I can't zip the file due to server restrictions.

Comment: @KyleMacey Pardon me if I missed the link, can you link it here?

Comment: Second link down in this threada by gpasci

Comment: @KyleMacey Rechecked. It uses jQuery UI - check left column under Choose Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this [plugin](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/) (5kb).

Comment: Thanks for supporting (while everybody was critical), Thanks a lot.. :)